# Insert float values to Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

This is my code, which inserts values in MS Access. But it doesn't insert float values, like `0.45`. The column datatype is `text`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into hhh VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" +textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "')";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Record Submitted", "Congrats");
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Does it insert anything else?
If yes, try to change either the database columntype to float(ms Access does not know double), or convert the values from the textBoxes to float

Comment: yes it's worked

Answer (score 1):

You insert everything as text while a float is a number. Also, ensure a proper string expression of the value, say for textBox1:

```
string text1;
// text1 must be formatted with dot as decimal separator.
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
text1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text).ToString(culture);

cmd.CommandText = "insert into hhh VALUES (" + text1 + ",'" +textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "')";
```

That said, *do* use parameters - simpler, proven, and preferred.